# Sprites in directx10 and texture filtering

Tags: c++, filtering, textures, sprite, directx-10

Is it possible to set different texture filtering when working with sprites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific about how you're drawing the sprites?

Texture filtering is determined by the ID3D10SamplerState objects bound to the device. If you're using the ID3DX10Sprite interface, it won't change the shaders or the samplers for each set of sprites, only the textures. So whatever shaders and samplers you've set before drawing the sprites will be used -- just set a sampler with the filtering mode you want before drawing the sprites.

Comment: I tried to do this with function PSSetSamplers(0, 1, _samplerState), but it doesn't work (in _samplerState structure I have standard settings but only filtering changed to point instead linear). Where it should be placed? I tried different combinations and no-one works.